# Почему происходит ошибка "The deploy step encountered an error: The process failed with exit code 128 ❌ Deployment failed"?

Tags: reactjs, json, github

Я использовал чужую сборку для реакт-приложения, клонировав себе репозиторий и связав его со своим новосозданным удаленным-репо на моем гите. Я внес изменения в `package.json`, и в `Actions` моего репозитория мне выбило ошибку при деплое:

```
Run JamesIves/github-pages-deploy-action@4.1.0

    GitHub Pages Deploy Action 

     Getting Started Guide: https://github.com/marketplace/actions/deploy-to-github-pages
    ❓ Discussions / Q&A: https://github.com/JamesIves/github-pages-deploy-action/discussions
     Report a Bug: https://github.com/JamesIves/github-pages-deploy-action/issues

     Maintained by James Ives: https://jamesiv.es
     Support: https://github.com/sponsors/JamesIves
Checking configuration and starting deployment… 
Deploying using Deploy Token… 
Configuring git…
/usr/bin/git config user.name ZnSt
/usr/bin/git config user.email 93055116+ZnSt@users.noreply.github.com
/usr/bin/git config --local --unset-all http.https://github.com/.extraheader
/usr/bin/git remote rm origin
/usr/bin/git remote add origin ***github.com/ZnSt/project-demo.git
Git configured… 
Starting to commit changes…
/usr/bin/git ls-remote --heads ***github.com/ZnSt/project-demo.git gh-pages
Creating worktree…
/usr/bin/git worktree add --no-checkout --detach github-pages-deploy-action-temp-deployment-folder
Preparing worktree (detached HEAD ca0201b)
/usr/bin/git checkout --orphan gh-pages
Switched to a new branch 'gh-pages'
Created the gh-pages branch… 
/usr/bin/git reset --hard
/usr/bin/git commit --no-verify --allow-empty -m Initial gh-pages commit
[gh-pages (root-commit) 4bca58a] Initial gh-pages commit
/usr/bin/rsync -q -av --checksum --progress /home/runner/work/project-demo/project-demo/build/. github-pages-deploy-action-temp-deployment-folder --delete --exclude CNAME --exclude .nojekyll --exclude .ssh --exclude .git --exclude .github
Checking if there are files to commit…
/usr/bin/git add --all .
/usr/bin/git checkout -b github-pages-deploy-action/2vx218o6m
Switched to a new branch 'github-pages-deploy-action/2vx218o6m'
/usr/bin/git commit -m Deploying to gh-pages from @ ZnSt/project-demo@ca0201bfaf143a1046c4072df5122f0f47d8a177  --quiet --no-verify
/usr/bin/git push --force ***github.com/ZnSt/project-demo.git github-pages-deploy-action/2vx218o6m:gh-pages
remote: Permission to ZnSt/project-demo.git denied to github-actions[bot].
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/ZnSt/project-demo.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
Running post deployment cleanup jobs… ️
/usr/bin/git worktree remove github-pages-deploy-action-temp-deployment-folder --force
Error: The deploy step encountered an error: The process '/usr/bin/git' failed with exit code 128 ❌
Deployment failed! ❌
Warning: The `set-output` command is deprecated and will be disabled soon. Please upgrade to using Environment Files. For more information see: https://github.blog/changelog/2022-10-11-github-actions-deprecating-save-state-and-set-output-commands/
```

Что я изменил: я поменял ссылку в `homepage`, на имя своего аккаунта в гите, а так же заменил названия своего репозитория. Возможно кто-то может подсказать суть проблемы и как ее можно решить?

Comment: Так у вас же написано "Permission to ZnSt/project-demo.git denied to github-actions[bot]" - Нет доступа до этого репозитория. Проверяйте настройки доступа. + В локальной репе смотрите, может забыли имя пользвоателя сменить

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо за помощь wolk8506, помогло!
От себя добавлю что эти настройки находятся в общих настройках(Settings) целевого репозитория в разделе Actions->General.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Возможно проблему получится решить настроив разрешения]

Возможно проблему получится решить настроив разрешения

Comment: пожалуйста, опишите словами, что именно вы предлагаете.

Answer (score 0):

Without these settings, the build will not have enough rights to automate the deployment process.
[image: Settings]

[image: SAVE]

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).